# iPhone OS syntax highlighting UITextField

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, syntax-highlighting, core-text

I am working on an application and would like to apply syntax highlighting to some user-entered text. I have looked around, and some people are suggesting that this can be done in iOS 3.2+ but posts seem to be from before the NDA was lifted. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about doing this?

I would be interested in releasing the code on github if I could get it implemented well, as I have never done so before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing for 3.2 and later, you can use NSAttributedString for this.

If you want to support earlier versions, using a UIWebView would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look into NSAttributedString.